# Flutter persistent notification and service

Tags: flutter, dart, service, notifications

I'm planning to develop simple audio player, but currently I'm stuck on notification support. I want notification that is persistent while audio is playing and I also need some controls (like play/pause, next/previous) and possibly fanart visible on notification. That's similar as most other player do (Aimp, Google Play Music etc).

I was looking forward for good example how to develop it using Dart/Flutter, well is that even possible without writing native code for each platform (Android/iOS)? Is there any plugin that supports that kind of notification on both platforms? Plus, of course, foreground service bound to it to don't kill audio playback when screen is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in looking at [package:audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) which seems like it might handle the majority of the work for you, including the handling of background execution and notifications.

Also, for notifications I've had success with [package:flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) but you shouldn't need this if you're going to use `package:audio_service`.

Comment: Excellent, it works (on Android at least, iOS not tested). I've been thinking about more advanced control and features, and use Bass audio library, but I think simple audio playback is ok at this point, writing it from scratch appears to be quite complicated.